# How do I make my ngDropdown menu work on hover instead of click?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using a template with Angular Bootstrap. I'm trying to call the dropdown event when i hover over it with my mouse instead of when i click on it. How can I call this event?

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block dropdown">
    <a class="navbar-brand" id="dropdownBasic1" href="#basiccomponents" ngbDropdownToggle>Learning</a>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1" class="dropdown-primary">
            <a class="dropdown-item">Learning Outcomes</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item">Learning Plan</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [dropdown API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/api) has a `toggle()` method, as well as explicit `open()` and `close()`. Call these on hover by binding to the `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` events.

Below are the basics, it is not a full example. You will need to provide a reference to your dropdown.

```html
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block dropdown" (mouseenter)="onHover($event)" (mouseleave)="onHover($event)">
  ...
<div>
```

```js
onHover(event): void {
  this.myDropDown.toggle();
}
```

Comment: After giving reference to dropdown, when you have multiple dropdowns in the same component it always opens the first element dropdown. But I am expecting to open only on the respective place where I am doing hover. Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide one named reference for each dropdown element using `@ViewChild`, you can then toggle these with individual methods, or use one method and get the element ref name from `event.target`

Comment: what is "myDropDown" ?. I see only ngbDropdownToggle, data-toggle="dropdown" But OP found this as an answer hmm

Comment: myDropDown is an @ViewChild ref ("You will need to provide a reference to your dropdown")

Answer (score 3):

Create a variable (whatever name) for your **ngbDropdown** in html template:
`#drop`

Give the typescript type **ngbDropdown**
`#drop="ngbDropdown"`

At event **mouseover** on **ngbDropdown** call the method:

```html
<li ngbDropdown #drop="ngbDropdown" (mouseover)='over(drop)'>
```

At event **mouseout** on **ngbDropdownMenu** call the method:

```html
<div ngbDropdownMenu (mouseout)='out(drop)'>
```

```js
  over(drop:NgbDropdown){
    drop.open()
  }
  out(drop:NgbDropdown){
    drop.close()
  }
```

```html
    <li class="nav-item" ngbDropdown #drop="ngbDropdown" display="dynamic" placement="bottom-end" (mouseover)='over(drop)' (mouseout)='out(drop)'>
      <a class="nav-link" tabindex="0" ngbDropdownToggle id="navbarDropdown3" role="button">
        Dynamic
      </a>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3" class="dropdown-menu">
        <a ngbDropdownItem href="#" (click)="$event.preventDefault()">Action</a>
        <a ngbDropdownItem href="#" (click)="$event.preventDefault()">Another action</a>
        <a ngbDropdownItem href="#" (click)="$event.preventDefault()">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using angular material with mouseleave and mouseenter evenets.

Reference: [https://www.thetopsites.net/article/54301126.shtml#:~:text=To%20hide%20menu%2C%20add%20mouseleave%20event%20for%20a%20menu.&text=Demos%20%3E%20Menu%2C%20Now%20on%20clicking,library%20to%20construct%20UI%2FUX](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/54301126.shtml#:%7E:text=To%20hide%20menu%2C%20add%20mouseleave%20event%20for%20a%20menu.&text=Demos%20%3E%20Menu%2C%20Now%20on%20clicking,library%20to%20construct%20UI%2FUX).
Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-toolbar-menu-wrut3v